# Ruby - evaluate string placeholder in variable at runtime

Tags: ruby

I have a string within a variable that contains a placeholder.  So quite literally I have this:

```
x = "something_\#{environment}"
```

I want to perform placeholder substitution of x at runtime with a value of environment that isn't available at the point x is defined.  I ultimately want to end up with:

```
y = "something_test"
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in Ruby?

Edit 1: this isn't solved using eval which is dead.  Hence the linked duplicate doesn't address my question.

Answer (score 3):

Use templates with `%`:

```
template = "something_%s"
#=> "something_%s"
x = template % ["test"]
#=> "something_test"
```

Comment: `%` also supports named placeholders: `'something_%{environment}' % {environment: 'test'}`

Comment: Named templates is exactly what I was looking for.  Didn't know I could use names with %.

Stefan if you put a new answer in I'll mark as accepted answer.